# Is it possible to make equally sized multipart rar archives from a big file?

Tags: file-management, rar, file-archiver, packer

Size of multipart archives is maximized at 200 MB. I would like to determine the part size (<200 MB), to achieve equally sized multipart archives.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. (If you already know how many parts your archive will be split into) Your command will be:

```
rar a -v$(( $(ls -s your_big_file | awk '{print $1}') / number_of_parts)) arcname your_big_file
```

Where:
`-v$(( $(ls -s your_big_file | awk '{print $1}') / number_of_parts))` tells rar to create volumes of the size of your file divided by the number of parts you want.

If you don't care about the number of parts and want them all to be 100MB for example, then your command will be much simpler:

```
rar a -v100m arcname your_big_file
```

Comment: You seem to be assuming (at least for the first part of your answer) that the OP has already determined how many parts to create.  That’s not how I interpret the question.

Comment: @Scott Yes, I am assuming. I modified the answer.